# Help Uninstalling Driver installed via dkms

Tags: wireless, drivers

I messed up the wifi driver of my Ralink RT3290 (very old laptop) trying to install the bluetooth driver, apparently there's no working bluetooth driver for RT3290 for kernel 4.2.0-34-generic. But I almost never use bluetooth so it's off topic.

I need help with removing/uninstalling driver installed using dkms. Here's the output of code :

```
oju@ubuntu:~$ dkms status
rt3290sta, 2.6.0.0, 4.2.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
```

This driver is currently in use by the system as shown in this link : http://pastebin.com/Fae3H5PG

This driver makes the wifi disconnect regularly(in around every 10 mins)
but I don't recall this happening with the driver that came with the OS.
What should I do now? Thanks For the Help!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can uninstall this driver by this command:

```
sudo dkms remove rt3290sta/2.6.0.0 --all
```

Comment: You answered it faster than it took me to format my question, Anways, I just Rebooted and I can confirm that it works like it did before. Appreciate the help.