# i915 Build/install Failure in LTS 16.04

Tags: 16.04, graphics, i915

I have been getting failures when performing software upgrades in LTS 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-45-generic.  The error goes something like "Error! Bad return value for ... i915 ...".  The i915 make.log file is telling me that the recipe for "/var/lib/dkms/i915-4.3.3-4.2.0/2/build/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_gem.o" and "/var/lib/dkms/i915-4.3.3-4.2.0/2/build" failed.

Background: I had installed the Intel graphics driver quite a while ago to fix some issues I was having, per recommendation from this board ([lightdm crash back to login Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725988/lightdm-crash-back-to-login-ubuntu-15-10?noredirect=1#comment1091300_725988)).  I'm guessing that the driver I'm using is simply dated and perhaps I need to update the driver or maybe even just remove it, if the Ubuntu-packaged drivers have fixed the original issue.

I'm not terribly savvy in Ubuntu when it comes to drivers, so I'd like confirmation of what the issue actually is and help on how to fix it (shell commands would be nice - a bash-Ninja I am not).

```
john@john-desktop:/var/lib/dkms/i915-4.3.3-4.2.0/2/build$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for john: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:b1000000-b1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If there are driver updates I seriously suggest updating. It looks like you may have misplaced/broken graphics driver files. In addition, you have a Broadwell CPU, which is fairly new and needs updates to maintain stability.

Comment: Thanks. If I go find the latest graphics driver and install it will it fix the broken driver file issues you mention?

Comment: It should. I suggest possibly trying to [purge/uninstall](http://askubuntu.com/questions/531540/how-to-safely-remove-proprietary-intel-driver) the Intel driver first.

Comment: You should be running kernel 4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04, seeing older versions in your description is quite confusing. I'd suggest to remove them, if you run into further issues and are unable to uninstall with the methods suggested you should look at the dkms manpage or answer like [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/752387/40581) to remove the Intel dmks modules.

Comment: I was able to use the intel-linux-graphic-installer that I already had and it seemed to do the job of upgrading my drivers.  Output of modinfo i915 shows 'filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/updates/dkms/i915.ko'.  Time will tell if I see the update errors again, but hopefully not.  Thanks!